# Using Bitmap class in android 2

Tags: android

I am trying Bitmap.When I run the it did not show image.I can not understand what i do.I am also trying **options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;** but not changed.Please help me:

my code here:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;

        Bitmap bMap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b,options);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bMap);


    }
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When I run the it did not show image

Comment: @user3659367 read http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use direct resource image to set up in ImageView.

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
```

When You using `inJustDecodeBounds` it just decodes black image with real image resolution.

Comment: what i do please tell me.. i want use bitmap

Comment: Maybe Your image is too big... You can add options.inSampleSize = 2;

Comment: Also you can try 3, 4, or more... But every number makes Your image with lower quality.

Comment: thank you bro @Roman Black....It is solved. bro what is common size for all photo supported ....(inSampleSize)

Comment: when You set inSampleSize = 1 Yuor image is decoding as is, when You set it = 2, Your picture is decoding with height/2 and width/2 resolution, when it = 3 it is decoding with height/4 and width/4 resolution and so on.

Comment: bro can you give your email id. when i post stackoverflow then i send your mail.

Answer (score 0):

Why Bitmap you need?
Did you try this?

```
imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the Options.inJustDecodeBounds to true and call the 
BitmapFactory's method to get/decode your bitmap, the bitmap returned 
will be null with the Options.outWidth and Options.outHeight to the image's width and height in pixels.

This is normally used to scale images. Cause you will get the image information before decoding it.

If you don't want to do such a thing, set Options.inJustDecodeBounds to false and your code will work. If you want to scale, take a look on this: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html